# WordPress page shows shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

My WordPress page shows shortcodes like [vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text] .
Help me identify the root cause.

I have migrated the wordpress sql files from one host to another.

Comment: Have you checked the settings of "Visual Composer" plugin? Those are the tags generated by that plugin. Try closing them in reverse order like, [/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row] at appropriate position in content.

Comment: thank you for the comments I didn't see visual composer plugin in dashboard, after site migration . The site was developed by some developer. Is it possible to retain the shortcode by installing the visual composer plugin and the reverse closing tags?

Comment: You'll need to add visual composer, also known as WP Bakery.  it's a common visual page builder.  the alternative is to use something like  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-utility-script-runner/ to iterate over all the posts and remove all of the [vc....] shortcodes from post content.

Answer (score 2):

I have got same result. My theme is wp baker. I activated edge core plugin and other required plug ins and it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify this [Utility Script Runner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-utility-script-runner/) script to remove shortcodes that no longer exist but are in your page content.  Definitely do this on staging before you do it on live.  high likelyhood of wrecking up the place.  This script has been sitting for close to a year and I honestly can't remember if any of it doesn't work as expected.  test a lot on staging before running this on anything you really care about.

```
<?php if(!defined('ABSPATH')) { die(); } 
/**
 * Utility Name: Remove and Flatten Shortcodes
 * Description: Strip Shortcodes from all posts, with several processing options
 * Supports: input
 * Version: 0.0.2
 **/

if (!class_exists('StripShortcodes')) {
    class StripShortcodes {
        var $wrappers = array(),
            $swaps = array();

        public static function Instance() {
            static $instance = null;
            if ($instance === null) {
                $instance = new self();
            }
            return $instance;
        }

        public function __construct() {
            add_filter('wp_util_script', array($this, 'strip_shortcodes_run'), 10, 3);
            add_filter('wp_util_input_html', array($this, 'strip_shortcodes_input_html'));
        }

        public function strip_shortcodes_input_html( $html ) {
            global $shortcode_tags;
            $post_types = get_post_types( array(
                'exclude_from_search' => false
            ), 'names' );
            $post_types = array_diff( $post_types, array( 'revision', 'attachment' ) );
            ?>
            <p>
                <strong>WARNING! DO NOT RUN THIS ON A LIVE SITE!</strong><br>
                This utility may cause data loss. Even restoring a backup may wipe out any changes since the last run of this utility.
            </p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="restore" value="restore"/>
                <span>Restore From Backup</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Post Types to Process</span>
                <select name="post_types[]" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="none" selected="selected">none</option>
                    <option value="any">all</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ) {
                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $post_type ) . '">' . $post_type . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </label>
            <hr/>
            <p>
                Select what you would like to do with each shortcode.
            </p>
            <?php
            if( !empty( $shortcode_tags ) ) {
                foreach( $shortcode_tags as $tag => $callable ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="shortcode-options-wrapper">
                        <label>
                            <span>[<?php echo $tag; ?>]</span>
                            <select class="shortcode-select" name="shortcodes[<?php echo esc_attr( $tag ); ?>]"/>
                            <option value="skip">Skip (do not process)</option>
                            <option value="strip">Remove (deletes shortcode content)</option>
                            <option value="unwrap">Unwrap Content</option>
                            <option value="parse">Flatten (parses to HTML)</option>
                            <option value="swap">Swap (Replace with another shortcode)</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            echo $this->build_form_script();
            return ob_get_clean();
        }

        private function build_form_script () {
            global $shortcode_tags;
            ob_start(); ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (jQuery)(function($) {
                    'use strict';

                    var unwrap = '<div class="wrap-wrapper"><p>Wrapper for content (use "sprintf()" formatting, including the %s for the content)</p><label>Wrapper<input class="shortcode-wrap"></label></div>';
                    var swap = '<div class="swap-wrapper"><select class="shortcode-swap"><?php foreach ($shortcode_tags as $tag => $callable) { echo '<option value="' . $tag . '">' . esc_attr($tag) . '</option>'; }?></select></div>'
                    $(document).on('change', '.shortcode-select', function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var name = $this.attr('name');
                        if ($this.val() == 'unwrap') {
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').append(unwrap);
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').find('.shortcode-wrap').attr('name', 'wrap_' + name);
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').find('.swap-wrapper').remove();
                        }
                        else if ($this.val() == 'swap') {
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').append(swap);
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').find('.shortcode-swap').attr('name', 'swap_' + name);
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').find('.wrap-wrapper').remove();
                        } else {
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').find('.wrap-wrapper').remove();
                            $this.closest('.shortcode-options-wrapper').find('.swap-wrapper').remove();
                        }
                    })
                });
            </script>
            <?php return ob_get_clean();
        }

        public function strip_shortcodes_run( $legacy, $state, $atts ) {
            $batch = 10;
            $offset = 0;
            if( !empty( $state['offset'] ) ) {
                $offset = $state['offset'];
            }
            $result = array(
                'state'   => 'error',
                'message' => 'an unknown error has occurred',
            );
            $post_types = 'none';
            if( !empty( $atts['post_types'] ) && !in_array( 'none', $atts['post_types'] ) ) {
                $post_types = $atts['post_types'];
            }
            $shortcode_settings = array();
            if( !empty( $atts['shortcodes'] ) ) {
                $shortcode_settings['core']    = $atts['shortcodes'];
                $shortcode_settings['wrap']    = $atts['wrap_shortcodes'];
                $shortcode_settings['swap']    = $atts['swap_shortcodes'];
            }

            $restore = true;
            if( empty( $atts['restore'] ) ) {
                $this->replace_shortcode_functions( $shortcode_settings );
                $restore = false;
            }
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'posts_per_page' => $batch,
                'offset' => $offset,
                'post_type' => $post_types
            ) );
            if( !$query->have_posts() ) {
                $result = array(
                    'state' => 'complete',
                    'message' => 'successfully processed all posts'
                );
            } else {
                $offset += $query->post_count;
                while( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $post = get_post();
                    $backup = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'flatten_shortcodes_backup', true );
                    if( $restore ) {
                        if( $backup ) {
                            $post->post_content = $backup;
                            wp_update_post( $post );
                            delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'flatten_shortcodes_backup' );
                        }
                    } else {
                        if( !$backup ) {
                            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'flatten_shortcodes_backup', $post->post_content );
                        }
                        $post->post_content = do_shortcode( $post->post_content );
                        wp_update_post( $post );
                    }
                }
                $result = array(
                    'state' => array(
                        'offset' => $offset
                    ),
                    'message' => $offset . ' posts processed'
                );
            }

            return $result;
        }

        private function replace_shortcode_functions( $settings = array() ) {
            global $shortcode_tags;
            foreach( $shortcode_tags as $tag => $callable ) {
                $setting = 'skip';
                if( !empty( $settings['core'][$tag] ) ) {
                    $setting = $settings['core'][$tag];
                }
                switch( $setting ) {
                    case 'strip' :
                        $shortcode_tags[$tag] = "__return_empty_string";
                        break;
                    case 'unwrap':
                        $shortcode_tags[$tag] = array($this, 'replace_shortcode_unwrap');
                        $this->wrappers[$tag] = $settings['wrap'][$tag];
                        break;
                    case 'parse' :
                        // nothing needed
                        break;
                    case 'swap' :
                        $shortcode_tags[$tag] = array($this, 'swap_shortcode');
                        $this->swaps[$tag] = $settings['swap'][$tag];
                        break;
                    case 'skip'  :
                    default      :
                        unset( $shortcode_tags[$tag] );
                }

            }
        }
        public function replace_shortcode_unwrap( $atts=array(), $content='', $tag ) {
            return sprintf($this->wrappers[$tag], $content);
        }
        public function swap_shortcode( $atts=array(), $content='', $tag ) {
            $attString = '';
            $newTag = $this->swaps[$tag];
            if (!empty($atts)) {
                foreach ($atts as $key => $att) {
                    $attString .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $att . '"';
                }
            }
            $output = '[' . $newTag . $attString . ']';
            if ($content) {
                $output .= $content . '[/' . $newTag . ']';
            }
            return $output;
        }
    }

    StripShortcodes::Instance();
}
```